# Implicit conversion of vector<shared_ptr<Foo> > to vector<shared_ptr<const Foo> >

Tags: c++, vector, casting, shared-ptr, implicit-conversion

According to [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) you can implicitly convert `shared_ptr<Foo>` to `shared_ptr<const Foo>`. That makes good sense.

However, I run into an error when I try to convert a `std::vector` containing `shared_ptr<Foo>` to one containing `shared_ptr<const Foo>`.

Is there a good way to achieve this conversion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No:  `std::vector<shared_ptr<Foo> >` and `std::vector<shared_ptr<const Foo> >` are different types, so you can't treat an object of one as an object of the other type.

If you really need a `std::vector<shared_ptr<const Foo> >`, you can easily create one with `shared_ptr`s to the same elements as the original:

```
std::vector<shared_ptr<Foo> > v;
std::vector<shared_ptr<const Foo> > cv(v.begin(), v.end());
```

However, if you write your code in terms of iterators, you shouldn't have any problem with this.  That is, instead of using

```
void f(const std::vector<shared_ptr<const Foo> >&);

// used as:
std::vector<shared_ptr<const Foo> > v;
f(v);
```

you should be using

```
template <typename ForwardIterator>
void f(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last);

// used as:
std::vector<shared_ptr<const Foo> > v;
f(v.begin(), v.end());
```

This way, the function `f` just requires that it gets a range of things that are usable as pointers to `const Foo` (or `shared_ptr<const Foo>`s, if the function assumes that the range contains `shared_ptr`s).

When a function takes a range instead of a container, you decouple the function from the underlying data:  it no longer matters what the data actually is or how it is stored, so long as you can use it in the way that you need to use it.

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you. I'll start using iterators more often when working with std and boost data structures.

Comment: Of course, `f(vector...)` is a non-template function while your Iterator fn is templated. And now, if you're going templated, you can *just as well* write `template <typename ContainerT> void f(ContainerT const&);` and be done with the iterator clutter.

Comment: @Lex:  If you have the time, Stephan T. Lavavej of the Visual C++ team has a series of [ten excellent lectures](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-10-of-10) in which he discusses the design philosophy of the STL and how to best use iterators to decouple how data is stored (containers) from how data is used (algorithms).

Comment: @Martin:  I disagree.  Iterators don't have to point into a container (or don't have to come directly from a container).  Transform and filter iterators are extremely useful for processing a range before passing it to a function.

Comment: @James: Certainly iterators are powerful. However, I only use them when I need that power. The `f` the OP wrote is very likely not a very generic function, so a simpler interface just taking a (templated) container type could make his code more readable than if he used iterators.

Comment: @James: (Don't get me wrong, iterators are great at what they do.) I just noticed how you "present iterators as the solution" to the OPs problem, when in fact the solution is *not* iterators but using a *template function* to allow for both different vector types. (This template function *can* be implemented in terms of taking an iterator pair, but it hasn't got to be.)

Comment: @Martin, on your statements *only use them when I need that power*, and *the OP wrote is very likely not a generic function*: Well, if he designed it with one type of vector in mind, and he needs to use it with another, chances are that *it should be generic* and *it needs that power*. On the shortcomings of @James McNellis approach, the worst issue is that a template cannot be virtual, and that might limit the usability of the *generic* approach --again *the `f` the OP wrote is very likely not a [virtual] function*.

Comment: Using iterators may be useful, but making the function a template is a very bad solution unless the function really is needed for many different types.

Answer (score 1):

`vector<TYPE>` and `vector<const TYPE>` are two different types. So without a hack or dirty code it is **not possible**.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need an `std::vector<shared_ptr<Foo const> >`?  The
conversion is easy; just use the two iterator constructor of
`std::vector`.  But in many cases, you won't need it: generally,
const-correctness isn't relevant for dynamically allocated
objects, and if you need a `shared_ptr<Foo const>`, there's an
automatic conversion when you extract the object from the
vector.